# Bash: write to the input stream of another process

Tags: bash

I have a script which reads variables from a input stream (not the standard where the pid =1).

```
#!/bin/sh

read u p

if [ "$u" == "user" -a "$p" == "pass" ]; then
  echo 'This works'
  exit 0
fi
```

I want to pass `u` and `p` from another script to the input stream of the above script. Any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Don't use `-a` as the AND operator; use `[ "$user" = "user" ] && [ "$p" = "pass" ]` instead.

Comment: @chepner could you please explain why?

Comment: See http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/test.html#tag_20_128_16.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use `|` (pipe). E.g.:

```
$ echo uu pp | bash -c 'read u p; echo $u $p'
uu pp
$
```

Comment: Why an explicit shell? Just compound it `echo uu pp | { read u p; echo "$u" "$p" ; }`

Comment: Why `echo "$u" "$p"`? Just `echo "$u $p".`

Comment: Why `echo`? It's not portable and behavior not fully standardized. Just `printf`.

Answer (score 2):

One solution :

```
1st_script
```

Output:

```
userX passX
```

So using an unix pipe `|`:

```
./1st_script | ./2th_script
```

Nothing to change in your script

Answer (score 1):

You can use [process substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Process-Substitution.html):

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

read -r u p < <(./some_script)
[[ $u = "user" && $p = "pass" ]] && echo "OK"
```